# php drop down list keeps one position

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created pogoda database, city table and columns city and cityid. I am using php to create a dynamic list and then submit chosen value into further code.

That is way I have added defult start position into drop down list (if statement in html).

After selecting value and clicking submit button everything works fine exepct dropdown list - it is always on the same position(defult) and I have no idea way. It is strange because other things which are also depending on submit button are working great.

My code bellow - db.inc.php:

```
 <?php
    define('DB_NAME','pogoda');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASS','');
    define('DB_HOST','localhost');
?>
```

func.inc.php

```
require_once 'db.inc.php';

function connect(){
    mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die('Could not connect to server!' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
}
function close(){
    mysql_close();
}
function query(){
    $myData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
        echo '<option value="' . $record['cityid'] . '">' . $record['city'] . '</option>';

    }
}

function get($name){
    return isset($_REQUEST[$name]) ? $_REQUEST[$name] : '';
}


?>
```

Part of html

```
        <div class="title">
        Pogoda
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <form>
            <select name="city">
                <?php query() ?>
            </select>
                <?php close() ?>
                <br>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
            <?php
                $cityid = get('city');

                if($cityid == NULL){
                $cityid = 4927854; //start position
                }
                else{
                $cityid = get('city'); //this one after clicking submit
                }
                echo $cityid; // test
                date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');
                use Cmfcmf\OpenWeatherMap;
                require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
                $lang = 'pl';
                $units = 'metric';
                $owm = new OpenWeatherMap("mycode");
                $forecast = $owm->getWeatherForecast( $cityid, $units, $lang, '', 3);
            ?>
</div>
```

[start value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB2mj.png)(numer shows curently chosen value). After seleccting different value and clicking submit as it is shown bellow all data in table is changing, test number is changing but value on the list is still the same [after submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5O9F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check which city is selected when you creating option list.
More or less like this:

```
function query($cityId){
    $myData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
        if($cityId == $record['cityid']){
            echo '<option selected value="' . $record['cityid'] . '">' . $record['city'] . '</option>';
        }else{
            echo '<option value="' . $record['cityid'] . '">' . $record['city'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
}


<select name="city">
    <?php query(get('cityid')) ?>
</select>
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything :( Regardles of value which I choose and submit my defult value is always selected on the list.